# Create Unique Hidden Field IDS from Select Menu options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, hidden-field

I have a modal that displays stock information for a specific item that has multiple locations within a warehouse. The user selects the locations and quantities from each menu and clicks confirm, the information from this modal needs to then be imported on a pick list which is printed out.

To do this I was planning to use arrays to transport the data to the pick list.

I have a hidden field for each row, containing the values of the Location and the Qty Picked from there.

> **Location 1 + Qty 1 = Hidden Field 1**
>
> **Location 2 + Qty 2 = Hidden Field 2**

I now want to be able to put those hidden fields into an array once a button is clicked.

> Hidden Field 1 + Hidden Field 2 = Array.

I can create the hidden fields just fine, its when I go to make the final array that contains all the data, it only seems to want to add the newest hidden field to be created into it.

**Dialog - Pick Quantity Button (Used to confirm the selections):**

```
//PICK QUANTITY Button
'Pick Quantity': function() {
    
jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(1)').button('disable');     
    
//Disables the current selection, so that it cannot be editted
$('#AddLocQtyPick'+Picker).prop ('disabled', true); 

//Disables the current selection, so that it cannot be editted
$('#LocationPickerSelect'+ Picker).prop ('disabled', true);  

//Adds Unique Number to the ID of the input fields
Picker++; 

//For Loop that helps to total up the quanities being selected in each picker
total=0;
for (i = 0; i<Picker; i++) {
total= total + $('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val() * 1.0;
}

//Variable decides max value of pick on appends using previous selection
QtyReqTot= QtyReq - total; 


//"Pick Another location" button is enabled whilst Qty Req has not been met
if (total !== QtyReq){
    jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(2)').button('enable');
}

//"Pick Quantity", "Pick Another Location" are disabled, whilst "Confirm" button is enabled when total reaches Qty Req
if (total == QtyReq){
    jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(2)').button('disable');
    jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(1)').button('disable');
    jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(3)').button('enable');
}

//Pick Another Location button is disabled if no more locations to pick from
if (length == 1){ 
    jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(2)').button('disable');
}

if (total !== QtyReq && length == 1){
    jQuery('.ui-dialog button:nth-child(1)').button('disable');
    $(":button:contains('Cancel')").focus();
}



//Create Hidden Field - Location

//for loop that creates the fields

for (i = 0; i<Picker; i++){
HiddenSelection = [$('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val(),$('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val()];
var appendHiddenSelection = '<input type="hidden" class="HiddenSelection'+ i +'" value='+HiddenSelection+'>';
$('#AddLocationPicker').append(appendHiddenSelection);  
alert(appendHiddenSelection +'This is SelectionField'+i);

}
},
```

**Confirm Button - Used to Generate the Final Array containing previous arrays:**

```
'Confirm': function() {     

//Reset the length loop
length = undefined;

//Remove "Multiple Location" icon from the row.
$('#icon'+id).hide();

//Checks "Multiple Location" icon for existence and adds Pick List button when all hidden.
$('img[id^=icon]:visible').length || $('#ProcessPickList').show();

//Change text colour back to blue to have visual confirmation that item is ready for picking
$('#Desc'+id).css('color', '#0000FF');
$('#QtyReq'+id).css('color', '#0000FF');
$('#QtyinStock'+id).css('color', '#0000FF');

//Create Total Array

TotalHiddenArray = [HiddenSelection]

alert (TotalHiddenArray);


$(this).dialog('close');
    
},
```

I think I need to be able to create unique IDS for the input fields and show how get them to all be added to the array.

Comment: "`TotalHiddenArray = [HiddenArray]`". Where's the declaration, and (possible) filling of the `HiddenArray`? Could you make your code a bit clearer?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer Sorry about that, I changed my code abit now, as well as edited my question. The variables used for the array are declared in the "Pick Quantity" section.

Comment: What is the question exactly, which part of your code are you having issues with. Is it possible to streamline it to that part? As an aside, `HiddenSelection` is an array, and you are setting it as the value of a form input field. How does that work for you?

Comment: The modal takes the values of Location and Qty and puts them in a hidden field. It does this for every line that is present. I then want to take all those hidden fields (1 generated per line) and put them into an array. However, when I try and do that, the array only contains the last hidden field that was created. I think I need to have each hidden field have a unique id and then when the array is created it loops through all of them and adds them into the array?

Comment: You have to take a look at the answer posted by Edensource. That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try replacing

```
HiddenArray = [appendHiddenQty, appendHiddenLocation]
```

By

```
HiddenArray[HiddenArray.length] = [appendHiddenQty, appendHiddenLocation]
```

This way, instead of overwriting `HiddenArray` within the loop, you just add `[appendHiddenQty, appendHiddenLocation]` at the end of `HiddenArray`.

---

EDIT1:

Replace

```
HiddenSelection = [$('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val(),$('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val()];
```

by

```
HiddenSelection[HiddenSelection.length] = [$('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val(),$('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val()];
```

Or, you also can use `push` :

```
HiddenSelection.push([$('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val(),$('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val()]);
```

> Please see this [quickly made Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fL0o4xa/)

---

EDIT2:

Ok, so let's try to replace the whole loop by:

```
var HiddenSelection = new Array;
for (i = 0; i<Picker; i++){
    HiddenSelection = [$('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val(),$('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val()];
    var appendHiddenSelection = '<input type="hidden" class="HiddenSelection'+ i +'"     value='+HiddenSelection+'>';
    $('#AddLocationPicker').append(appendHiddenSelection);  
    alert(appendHiddenSelection +'This is SelectionField'+i);

    TotalHiddenArray.push([HiddenSelection]);
}
```

You just have to remove this from your `confirm` function :

```
//Create Total Array
TotalHiddenArray = [HiddenSelection]
```

You also have to delcare `TotalHiddenArray` as new array outside any function (at the very top of your JS code for exemple, because I guess you are trying to access `TotalHiddenArray` from another function than the loop) like this :

```
var TotalHiddenArray= new Array;
```

> Another [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fL0o4xa/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EdenSource, I thought I had time for a quick edit before anyone posted an answer as I've changed my question and code a little bit. Have another look and let me know if you can help.

Comment: The hint should be the same, please see the edit in answer.

Comment: Doesn't like that, says that HiddenSelection is not defined when I do that change.

Comment: You have to declare your Array before pushing new elements in it : `var HiddenSelection = new Array;`

Comment: I know your answer will work, I'm just not sure how to type it into my code. I really am a beginner! I get things like the same field posting twice in the array or a hidden field getting pushed into another hidden field. I know I'm declaring the array incorrectly

HiddenSelection = [$('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val(),$('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val()]
HiddenSelection.push([$('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val(),$('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val()]);
var appendHiddenSelection = '<input type="hidden" class="HiddenSelection'+ i +'" value='+HiddenSelection+'>';
$('#AddLocationPicker').append(appendHiddenSelection);

Comment: Ah, so the array is basically overwriting itself and increasing every time a new row is added to it? Keeping it up to date?

Comment: If you use `HiddenSelection = [$('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val(),$('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val()];`, yes it is overwriting. If you use `.push()`, it is adding a new entry to the array.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, I have learnt something! I believe it is working now. I can now focus on the next part of my project!

FYI - It was EDIT 2 that was the great help, if you want to edit your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please ask if anything else is wrong ;)